# Regex matching whitespaces in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expresion to validate paths of type Number/string/string that looks so: `^[0-9]{1,}(/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)*$`

If I'm right it should not allow whitespaces, this should be invalid:

```
2/Pathtest/thirdlevel/bla bla
```

In online testers like [Myregextester](https://myregextester.com) it works as expected, but in my c# code it returns true with whitespaces... what am I doing wrong?

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetDirectoryName(folder.Path).Replace("\\", "/"), @"^[0-9]{1,}(/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)*$"))
{
    throw new ArgumentException(Resources.Strings.FileNameNotAzureCompatible);
}
```

Comment: Can you simplify your example code with two simple example strings, one of which you expect it to match (and it does) and one of which you expect it to not match? Rather than have us guess what `folder.Path` values might be causing your problems?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The GetDirectoryName was confusing me. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pattern = @"^[0-9]{1,}(/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)*$";
        string shouldNotMatchString = @"2/Pathtest/thirdlevel/bla bla";
        bool shouldBeFalse = Regex.IsMatch(shouldNotMatchString, pattern);

        string shouldMatchString = @"2/Pathtest/thirdlevel/blabla";
        bool shouldBeTrue = Regex.IsMatch(shouldMatchString, pattern);
    }
```

guess what....shouldBeFale is false, shouldBeTrue is true. your regex seems to be fine.

Comment: You where right... The regex was ok, it was a problem with the GetDirectoryName function!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems wrong.
You should escape the `/`:

```
^[0-9]{1,}(\/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)*$
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any regex engine that considers forward slashes to have special meaning and require escaping. Certainly the [.NET one doesn't](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Ah, okay, yes. It need to be delimited if you're working in a language that uses forward slashes for regex literals. (If you switch it to Python there, you'll notice the error goes away). C# isn't such a language.